# sftp JSch transfer file to remote cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sftp, file-transfer, jsch

I am trying copy files from local windows machine to remote windows machine using `sftp JSch`. Remote machine has `cygwin`, but file is not getting transferred. While doing, it is not throwing any error.

I tried with different destination path format like `/cygdrive/d/` and also `d://`.

```
String destination = "/cygdrive/d/Test1";
String source = "D:\\Test";

List<String> files = NFileUtils.listFiles(source);
for (String f : files) {
    String fileName = NFileUtils.getFilename(f);
    try {
        sftp.put(f, destination + "\\" + fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: which server sftp is used on cygwin side ?

Comment: its on a windows machine

Comment: I mean which software used as sftp server. Have you tested it with some sftp client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sftp.put(f, destination + "\\" + fileName);
```

SFTP uses a file-naming model in which "/" is the directory separator character. Try using "/" as the path separator instead of "\":

```
sftp.put(f, destination + "/" + fileName);
```

If `fileName` contains any "\" characters, you'll need to change them as well.

Comment: i tried this..Even its not helping.No errors,Nothing.But file is not getting transfered.

Comment: it helped me.Thanks!